# Can't get a search box to stretch until a certain width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify a search box to have it to be centered and stretch until a max wdth while I the browser window.
I'm not good at coding, but I tried to modify the ccs. Now it is centered in the container but it doesn't stretch to a max width (like 400px or so) Actual css of the containervis:

```
.jr-form-adv-search-module {
margin: auto;
margin-top:10px;
width:50% ;
```

}

the search module has a search box and a button.

.jrKeywords
.jrButton

I want the button to stay the same witdh but the search box (the text input part) to stretch until it reaches 400px while I resize the window. Now only the container ".jr-form-adv-search-module" follows the window while .jrKeywords stays small. I tried a lot of combinations but I can't get it to stretch.

[Search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kadIE.png)

This is the search bar. To resume I want the white text input to stretch until 400px while the search button and him stays centered. At the moment only the gray container follows the window.

This is the searchbox code

```
<div class="jr-page jrPage jrAdvSearchModule jrRoundedPanel jrForm">

<form class="jr-form-adv-search-module" action="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=jreviews_ajax" method="post" data-live-search="1" data-live-search-hide="1" data-module-id="jreviewsadvsearchwidget-2">






    <div class="jrFieldDiv jrLeft" style="">

         <input type="text" class="jrKeywords" name="data[keywords]" value="" style="height:37px;">

    </div>



    <div class="jrFieldDiv jrLeft">

        <button class="jr-search jrButton" style="margin:0; font-size:120%; background: #289dcc;color:#ffffff; border-color:#289dcc;">

            <span class="jrIconSearch"></span><span>Search</span>

        </button>

    </div>



    <div class="jrClear"></div>


    <input name="data[contentoptions][]" type="hidden" value="title">

    <input name="data[contentoptions][]" type="hidden" value="introtext">

    <input name="data[contentoptions][]" type="hidden" value="fulltext">


    <input name="data[search_query_type]" type="hidden" value="all">


    <input type="hidden" name="data[controller]" value="search">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[action]" value="_process">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[menu_id]" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[dir]" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[Search][criteria_id]" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[form_id]" value="JreviewsAdvSearch_jreviewsadvsearchwidget-2">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[module_id]" value="jreviewsadvsearchwidget-2">



        </form>


    <div class="jrClear"></div>


    <input name="data[contentoptions][]" type="hidden" value="title">

    <input name="data[contentoptions][]" type="hidden" value="introtext">

    <input name="data[contentoptions][]" type="hidden" value="fulltext">


    <input name="data[search_query_type]" type="hidden" value="all">


    <input type="hidden" name="data[controller]" value="search">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[action]" value="_process">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[menu_id]" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[dir]" value="">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[Search][criteria_id]" value="1">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[form_id]" value="JreviewsAdvSearch_jreviewsadvsearchwidget-2">

    <input type="hidden" name="data[module_id]" value="jreviewsadvsearchwidget-2">
```

I'm using the possibility of my wordpress theme to add custom css to modify the search box behaviour. This is what I've added so far:

```
.jr-form-adv-search-module {
margin: auto;
margin-top:10px;
width:50% ;
```

}

Comment: Hi Stefano, include all of the code needed to replicate the layout. The width of the element will depend on it's parent elements, which you didn't include. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: done. hope it is ok. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max-width` property.

Give a class to the input parent, let's say `input-container`. You can use these rules:

```
.input-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

With this, the div will try to fill all the space in width, but il will stop growing when it reaches the maximum width of 400px. And when you resize the page below 400px, the div will take 100% width.

Comment: thanks. Had to stretch jrLeft before stretching the input field because that was the stopper. Your reply was helpful.

Comment: @StefanoV. please consider accepting this answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
.jr-form-adv-search-module {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```